# MSVC C++ 17 get lexically normalized path

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Assume I have a path `p = "C:/some/./path/`. I want the normalized path `C:/some/path/`. I know there is a function [path::lexically_normal()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal) which (according to cppreference.com) is part of C++ 17. However, according to page 16 in the [open std draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4100.pdf) (which is referenced in the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem) from Microsoft), `path::lexically_normal()` is not part of the `path` class and thus the function doesn't exist in MS' implementation.

Are there any alternatives to this (preferebly within the stdlib)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio implements the FileSystem TS. This is why you have to spell it `std::experimental::filesystem::path` instead of `std::filesystem::path`.

However, when C++17 incorporated the FileSystem TS, they *changed* things. This includes [additions like `lexically_normal`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0219r1.html).

There is no alternative because `lexically_normal` is what you're supposed to use. That's why it was added in C++17. You'll just have to wait until VS implements C++17 fully.